# C# - find the position of a string inside a predefined string array

Tags: c#, arrays, string

I have a predefined string array with the letters from `A` to `Q` :

```
string[] SkippedAreasArray = new string[] {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G",
            "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q"};
```

In a `TextBox` inside Windows Form the user can enter skippedAreas like this: `A,B,C,D...` there is validations and restrictions to use only letters and commas so the input is guaranteed to be in this format.

What I do is taking the user input and populate another string array:

```
string[] SkippedAreasFromForm = new string[17];
...
SkippedAreasFromForm = (txtSkippedAreas.Text).Split(',');
```

Now comes the tricky part for which I'm seeking assistance. The user must enter `Number of areas` for example - 3. Which mean he is working only with `A`, `B`, and `C`. If the number of areas was 2 then he can only use `A` and `B` if the number of areas was 4 then `A`, `B`, `C` and `D` are available and so on.

What I need is to check if in the array `SkippedAreasFromForm` which is populated with the user input there is an area that doesn't match the above criteria.

What this mean in terms of coding - I need to take every element from  `SkippedAreasFromForm`, take it's integer value from the predefined `SkippedAreasArray` and see if this value is equal or greater (>=) of the value that he entered as `Number of areas. If there is an area which is outside the scope of the selected number an error should be shown.

What I have right now is :

```
foreach (string tempAreaValue in SkippedAreasFromForm)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < SkippedAreasArray.Length; i++)
                    {
                        if (tempAreaValue == SkippedAreasArray[i])
                        {
                            if ((i + 1) > entity.AreasCnt)
                            {
                                MessageBox.Show("You must use areas only within the Number of Areas scope!", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                                txtSkippedAreas.Focus();
                                return false;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
```

For the few test I made it works. But first - at least for me it seems over complicated. Second - I'm not sure that this algorithm is working exactly as I need to or I'm just having correct results by luck. Third - I'm coding C# for 2months now and this seems to me like an excellent candidate for a LINQ expression - do you think it would be better using LINQ and I would appreciate a help in the transformation.

Comment: What if the user types "A,B,C,K" and types number 4? Is K accepted in this case?

Comment: No there is validation before the code in my post is executed and the validation guarantees only `A-Q` values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you're just looking for `IndexOf`:

```
int index = SkippedAreasArray.IndexOf(tempAreaValue);
if (index >= entity.AreasCnt)
{
    ...
}
```

(You might also want to check for `index` being -1, which would occur if the element wasn't in the list at all. Also, consider duplicates - can the user enter `A`, `A`, `A`?)

Comment: The element will be in the list - that's guaranteed with iput validation of the fields. If there is something entered it is something from this list (by the way I don't like declaring the array for `A-Q` letter, what would say about that?) and the duplicating inserts is something that I missed and I thank you for that.

Comment: @Leron: While there certainly *are* ways of avoiding creating the array, it's probably the simplest approach, to be honest.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for the elements in the array from start index to max string elements based on areaNumber, then:

```
int areaNumber = 4;
var result = SkippedAreasArray.Select((r, i) => new { Value = r, Index = i })
                              .Where(r => r.Index <= areaNumber - 1)
                              .Select(r => r.Value)
                              .ToArray();
```

For `areaNumber 4` you will get `"A", "B", "C", "D"`

**EDIT:**

> I'm looking if every element from the user input (which is array
>   A,C,H,Q..) is inside the area determined from the areNumber *(from comment)*

Suppose your userInputArray is:

```
string[] userInputArray = new string[] {"A", "C", "H", "Q"};
```

Then you can use `Enumerable.Except` in the following manner:

```
if(result.Except(userInputArray).Any())
{
  //Invalid
}
else
{
 //Valid
}
```

Comment: Well this might help but I have to change the logic. I'm looking if every element from the user input (which is array `A,C,H,Q..`) is inside the area determined from the `areNumber`.

Comment: @Leron, If I understood it correctly then you can use Enumerable.Except, like I did in my edit part of he answer